# Asynctask with webservices in android

Tags: android, web-services, android-asynctask

i need help.. i'm trying to call php webservices from my android client application ,and i couldn't call it from main thread coz the SDK is 15 ,and I search on the web and I found the solution for this problem is to use the Asynktask .. but it doesn't work with me i don't know why .. any help please ..Thank you

```
public class CustomWebConnection extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
private final String                 uri = "http://localhost/mywebservices.php?op=GetAllRest";
private ArrayList<NameValuePair>     mParams;
private OnPostExecuteListener        mPostExecuteListener = null;

public static interface OnPostExecuteListener{
    void onPostExecute(String result);
}

CustomWebConnection(ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs,
    OnPostExecuteListener postExecuteListener) throws Exception {

    mParams = nameValuePairs;
    mPostExecuteListener = postExecuteListener;
    if (mPostExecuteListener == null)
        throw new Exception("Param cannot be null.");
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

      JSONObject param=null;
      String result = null;
      HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpHost httpHost = new HttpHost("localhost",80);  
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri);
        httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");


        try
        {
            //HttpEntity bodyEntity = new StringEntity(param.toString(), "utf8");
            //httpPost.setEntity(bodyEntity);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            if (entity != null) {
                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                     new InputStreamReader(instream));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();


                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    sb.append(line + "\n");


                result = sb.toString();
                instream.close();           
            }
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    httpPost.abort();
    return result ;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if (mPostExecuteListener != null){
        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
            mPostExecuteListener.onPostExecute(result);
        } catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and it's throw this exception

```
     04-09 16:31:37.393: E/AndroidRuntime(2284): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     04-09 16:31:37.393: E/AndroidRuntime(2284): java.lang.NullPointerException
      04-09 16:31:37.393: E/AndroidRuntime(2284):   at    org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
     04-09 16:31:37.393: E/AndroidRuntime(2284):    at  org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
      04-09 16:31:37.393: E/AndroidRuntime(2284):   at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:154)
     04-09 16:31:37.393: E/AndroidRuntime(2284):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
  04-09 16:31:37.393: E/AndroidRuntime(2284):   at  com.vtab.CustomWebConnection.onPostExecute(CustomWebConnection.java:92)
 04-09 16:31:37.393: E/AndroidRuntime(2284):    at com.vtab.CustomWebConnection.onPostExecute(CustomWebConnection.java:1)
 04-09 16:31:37.393: E/AndroidRuntime(2284):    at  android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
 04-09 16:31:37.393: E/AndroidRuntime(2284):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
 04-09 16:31:37.393: E/AndroidRuntime(2284):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
 04-09 16:31:37.393: E/AndroidRuntime(2284):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 04-09 16:31:37.393: E/AndroidRuntime(2284):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  04-09 16:31:37.393: E/AndroidRuntime(2284):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
  04-09 16:31:37.393: E/AndroidRuntime(2284):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  04-09 16:31:37.393: E/AndroidRuntime(2284):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  04-09 16:31:37.393: E/AndroidRuntime(2284):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
  04-09 16:31:37.393: E/AndroidRuntime(2284):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
 04-09 16:31:37.393: E/AndroidRuntime(2284):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

the error at `HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);`

and this is the **JSON response** from the server

```
[{"rest_id":"1","rest_name":"Al Dabke","cuisine":"Lebanese","no_tables":"15","bg_img":"lebanon","rest_logo":"dabke"},{"rest_id":"4","rest_name":"MY KIND OF PLACE","cuisine":null,"no_tables":"10","bg_img":"kindofplacebg","rest_logo":"mykindofplacelogo"},{"rest_id":"5","rest_name":"LANTANIA","cuisine":"Thai","no_tables":"10","bg_img":"lantaniabg","rest_logo":"lantanialogo"},{"rest_id":"6","rest_name":"LEONARDO","cuisine":"italian","no_tables":"10","bg_img":"leonardobg","rest_logo":"leonardologo"},{"rest_id":"7","rest_name":"LE MARCHE ","cuisine":"French","no_tables":"10","bg_img":"lemarchebg","rest_logo":"lemarchelogo"},{"rest_id":"8","rest_name":"Marias","cuisine":"mexican","no_tables":"10","bg_img":"mariang","rest_logo":"marialogo"},{"rest_id":"9","rest_name":"NOBLE HOUSE","cuisine":"chinese","no_tables":"10","bg_img":"noblehousebg","rest_logo":"noblehouselogo"}]
```

any help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also face this issue recently and i found that HttpClient is problem in Android ICS ,,, The simple hack i used is to change min SDK version to 7 from 15. But its isnt a proper solution. i come across the code from a blog

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.
ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Putting this in onCreate() method has solved my problem. May be it can help you. still i am looking for some more options.

Comment: i got this error and i this this is why the NullPointerException is appear .. i got this  org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost refused ..and i don't run from emulator i used a device .. how can i solve this problem..thank you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the error was in parsing the JSON, although you're not getting a JSONException.

Comment: What if you posted the JSON to verify? The right way to fix it would be to make sure the server if sending valid JSON, if that is indeed what is going on.

Comment: i post the JSON and it is valid .. i don't know what is the problem

Comment: It looks like the JSON is an Array, and you're using JSONObject instead of JSONArray. I'm not sure if that would cause a problem or not. I'll test it in a minute.

Comment: On my system, loading that into a JSONObject gives me a JSONException, whereas loading it into JSONArray works just fine. You however are getting a NullPointerException. Maybe that's a difference in SDK levels?